# Яндекс блок «Поделиться» не появляется в динамически добавленном блоке

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

История такая: сайт из одной страницы, есть изначально скрытый (display:none) блок #ghost, в нем изначально пустой блок '.albom'. При клике на пункт меню JQ шуршит по базе картинок, находя подходящие делает $('.albom').append("
В этом аппенде к каждой '.picture' добавляется блок ya-share2 с параметрами соответствующей картинки.
Сразу после добавления я пытяюсь его инициализировать. Судя по всему неправильно.

Перечитал документацию и местные вопросы - ничего не помогло. Блок на сайте не виден.

Что я с этим Ya.share2 делаю не так?
Вопрос чайника. Первый сайт в моей жизни.

```js
var findImages = function(mat, headText, bckGrnd) { //searches in myWorks array and creates .picture block for every appropriate image

  var imgCount = myWorks.length;
  if ($('.albom').html() == '') pictureID = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < imgCount; i++) {
    if (myWorks[i].material == mat) {          
      
      $('.albom').append("<div class='picture' id='" + pictureID++ +"'>" + 
        "<img src='" + myWorks[i].lnk + "'>" +
        "<div class='ya-share2' data-services='facebook,vkontakte,twitter,gplus' data-lang='en'" +
        "data-description='" + myWorks[i].name + " by Alex Titenkov' " +
        "data-image='http://www.test.ru/" + myWorks[i].lnk + "'></div>" +
        "</div>"
      ); //end of append

      var share = Ya.share2('pictureID', { //инициализация блока Поделиться
        content: {
          url: 'https://yandex.com'
        }
      });
    };
  };

  $('#ghost').css('display', 'block');  //показываем заполненный альбом
};
```

Comment: Есть возможность дать ссылку на страницу или привести код страницы целиком?

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из логики, что надо запустить скрипт после добавления блока, прямо в .append() добавил

```js
"<script src='https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js' async='async'></script>"
```

Заработало.
При этом "var share = Ya.share2..." вообще не нужен.
Но, мне кажется, это как-то криво.
Умные, посоветуйте, а?